# Would you be able to see yourself in a mirror in front of you as you two are in a room traveling at the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reflection

Veritasium talked about this in one video. If you are in a room or a train, plane, car or whatever just a closed space traveling at the speed of light and you put a mirror in front of you, could you see your reflection? I think the answer is no because light can't travel 2 times "c", light can't travel from you (because you already go to that speed) to the mirror.

Comment: If you don't want your question closed quickly as a duplicate, you must modify your question since, as has been asked and answered here too many times to count, *there is no inertial reference frame with speed $c$*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reflection at speed of light when both mirror and viewer is travelling at the speed of light](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67712/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you see yourself in a mirror when you are riding on top of a light stream?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8163/)

Comment: See also my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91149/)